# Getting UDP-socket send timestamps using ioctl

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, system-calls

You can get the most recent time a message was received for a UDP-socket by using `ioctl(sfd, SIOCGSTAMP, &recv_time)`. Is there a similar way to get the timestamp for the last package sent by a socket? Or do I have to resort to a more complicated way using `setsockopt`?

I've already looked into the man pages but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I doubt it's possible. You can't even know is datagram actually sent or not. You can get system time next to `send()` call, it will be rough timestamp.